# values do not match for each id

Tags: javascript, html

Right now the age marks, IELTS marks, and total marks do not match their values and I don't know why. The problem is that the value appears is the previous value I clicked, not current one.

```
<form>
        <input type="radio" id="age0" name="age" value="20" onblur="getTotal()">age 18 &nbsp 20 marks<br>
        <input type="radio" id="age1" name="age" value="30" onblur="getTotal()">age 19 &nbsp 30 marks <br>
        <input type="radio" id="age2" name="age" value="40" onblur="getTotal()">age 20 &nbsp 40marks <br><br>
</form>
<form>
        <input type="radio" id="language0" name="language" value="48" onblur="getTotal()"> IELTS(4.5、4.0、3.5、4.0)&nbsp 48 marks <br>
        <input type="radio" id="language1" name="language" value="68" onblur="getTotal()"> IELTS(5.0、5.0、4.0、5.0）&nbsp 68 marks <br>
        <input type="radio" id="language2" name="language" value="80" onblur="getTotal()"> IELTS(5.5、5.5、5.0、5.5）&nbsp 80 marks <br>
        <input type="radio" id="language3" name="language" value="88" onblur="getTotal()"> IELTS(6.0、6.0、6.0、6.0）&nbsp 88 marks <br>
        <input type="radio" id="language4" name="language" value="100" onblur="getTotal()"> IELTS(7.5、6.5、6.5、6.5）&nbsp 100 marks <br><br>
</form>
    age marks： &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <input type = "text" id="totalAge"> <br><br>
    IELTS marks： &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <input type = "text" id="totalLang"> <br><br>
    total marks： <input type = "text" id="total"> <br><br><br>


<script>
function getTotal() {
    var theAge = document.getElementsByName('age');
    var theLang = document.getElementsByName('language');
    var totalAge = 0;
    var totalLang = 0;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < theAge.length; i++) {
        if (theAge[i].checked) {
            totalAge = theAge[i].value;
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < theLang.length; i++) {
        if (theLang[i].checked) {
            totalLang = theLang[i].value;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('totalAge').value = totalAge;
    document.getElementById('totalLang').value = totalLang;
    document.getElementById('total').value = parseInt(totalAge) + parseInt(totalLang);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, Can you elaborate on what exactly your code is doing and what is expected output?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'd like to choose either from age0, age1 or age2 value, and either from language0 or ... language5 value, and show up their value and also add them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `onchange` instead of `onblur` it will work as expected.

Why onblur is not working?

When you choose a radio option, the radio button will be in focus state untll you click somewhere else, that is why your first value get updated when you click on the second radio button.

```js
function getTotal() {
  var theAge = document.getElementsByName('age');
  var theLang = document.getElementsByName('language');
  var totalAge = 0;
  var totalLang = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < theAge.length; i++) {
    if (theAge[i].checked) {
      totalAge = theAge[i].value;
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < theLang.length; i++) {
    if (theLang[i].checked) {
      totalLang = theLang[i].value;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('totalAge').value = totalAge;
  document.getElementById('totalLang').value = totalLang;
  document.getElementById('total').value = parseInt(totalAge) + parseInt(totalLang);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" id="age0" name="age" value="20" onchange="getTotal()">age 18 &nbsp 20 marks<br>
  <input type="radio" id="age1" name="age" value="30" onchange="getTotal()">age 19 &nbsp 30 marks <br>
  <input type="radio" id="age2" name="age" value="40" onchange="getTotal()">age 20 &nbsp 40marks <br><br>
</form>
<form>
  <input type="radio" id="language0" name="language" value="48" onchange="getTotal()"> IELTS(4.5、4.0、3.5、4.0)&nbsp 48
  marks <br>
  <input type="radio" id="language1" name="language" value="68" onchange="getTotal()"> IELTS(5.0、5.0、4.0、5.0）&nbsp 68
  marks <br>
  <input type="radio" id="language2" name="language" value="80" onchange="getTotal()"> IELTS(5.5、5.5、5.0、5.5）&nbsp 80
  marks <br>
  <input type="radio" id="language3" name="language" value="88" onchange="getTotal()"> IELTS(6.0、6.0、6.0、6.0）&nbsp 88
  marks <br>
  <input type="radio" id="language4" name="language" value="100" onchange="getTotal()"> IELTS(7.5、6.5、6.5、6.5）&nbsp 100
  marks <br><br>
</form>
age marks： &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <input type="text" id="totalAge"> <br><br>
IELTS marks： &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <input type="text" id="totalLang"> <br><br>
total marks： <input type="text" id="total"> <br><br><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is occurring because on onblur. Short Answer -> Change **onblur** to **onchange** and your problem should be fixed.

Reason: onblur fires when a field loses focus and onchange fires when field value changes. In your case changes are not reflected until you move your focus out of the field and that is the reason for seeing a different answer than expected.

```html
<form>
        <input type="radio" id="age0" name="age" value="20" onchange="getTotal()">age 18 &nbsp 20 marks<br>
        <input type="radio" id="age1" name="age" value="30" onchange="getTotal()">age 19 &nbsp 30 marks <br>
        <input type="radio" id="age2" name="age" value="40" onchange="getTotal()">age 20 &nbsp 40marks <br><br>
    </form>
    <form>
        <input type="radio" id="language0" name="language" value="48" onchange="getTotal()"> IELTS(4.5、4.0、3.5、4.0)&nbsp 48 marks <br>
        <input type="radio" id="language1" name="language" value="68" onchange="getTotal()"> IELTS(5.0、5.0、4.0、5.0）&nbsp 68 marks <br>
        <input type="radio" id="language2" name="language" value="80" onchange="getTotal()"> IELTS(5.5、5.5、5.0、5.5）&nbsp 80 marks <br>
        <input type="radio" id="language3" name="language" value="88" onchange="getTotal()"> IELTS(6.0、6.0、6.0、6.0）&nbsp 88 marks <br>
        <input type="radio" id="language4" name="language" value="100" onchange="getTotal()"> IELTS(7.5、6.5、6.5、6.5）&nbsp 100 marks <br><br>
    </form>
    age marks： &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <input type = "text" id="totalAge"> <br><br>
    IELTS marks： &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <input type = "text" id="totalLang"> <br><br>
    total marks： <input type = "text" id="total"> <br><br><br>


<script>
function getTotal() {
    var theAge = document.getElementsByName('age');
    var theLang = document.getElementsByName('language');
    var totalAge = 0;
    var totalLang = 0;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < theAge.length; i++) {
        if (theAge[i].checked) {
            totalAge = theAge[i].value;
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < theLang.length; i++) {
        if (theLang[i].checked) {
            totalLang = theLang[i].value;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('totalAge').value = totalAge;
    document.getElementById('totalLang').value = totalLang;
    document.getElementById('total').value = parseInt(totalAge) + parseInt(totalLang);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Glad, I was able to help @April. Happy Coding !!